# link for nested list

Tags: html, html-lists

I would like the entire box to be a link to my page tomatoes.html, however the user has to click ***specifically*** on the word "tomatoes" to go to the new page. How can I make its surrounding box also a link?  I tried to do

```
<a><li>a href="tomatoes.html">Tomatoes</li></a>
```

but my research tells me this is not proper HTML coding.  Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<div class="subMenu subGrub">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="tomatoes.html">Tomatoes</a></li>
      <li><a href="potatoes.html">Potatoes</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave it to this:

```
<li><a href="tomatoes.html">Tomatoes</a></li>
```

and use this CSS to get the whole `<li>`-element to be "clickable":

```
li > a {
    display: block;
}
```